# Note taking app that doesn't truncate notes, display full notes back to back in main view area?

Tags: note-taking

I've been struggling to find something which I thought would be a common option in note taking apps.

I collect tips & tricks for a certain subject, and what I need is the ability to collect them inside a single place, tag them and read them by tag.

But, the problem is most note taking apps truncate longer notes, so you have to manually open each of the longer notes. For instance Google Keep, I could survive the fact that it doesn't support tags, but it's unusable for me since it truncates the longer notes.

So basically, I want to choose a tag and read all the notes tagged with it by just swyping or scrolling, without the need to manually open any message.

Windows & Android support is highly desired, but I'm mostly interested in Windows. Though advanced text editing abilities and inserting of linking and images is desired, I would accept plain text format.

Comment: So these are short notes? Otherwise displaying the full-length notes on a dashboard might not be possible.

Comment: Some are short, some are long. This seems so simple and obvious, but nothing works. I am on the verge of using an Excel spreadsheet with filtering :)

Comment: So something like [Trello](http://trello.com)? ([Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/cDMYRc1.png))

Comment: Hmmm, that could work. But, it doesn't support tags, rather labels that act as tags, right? I fiddled a bit with it and it seems to work ok.

How does it translate to mobile? Any way of filtering by labels?

Comment: You can actually label with colours (or your own custom labels) then filter by that. The interface is similar on mobile, just limited to a single list taking up the small screen.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion.